TYPO3 v12 upgrade: DCE: migrate group, internal_type==db
I have some DCE configurations with group, internal_type: db
As I read, this configurations is completely removed now. It was used to select an image file with an "Resource Browser" popup.
Does somebody know a solution, how to migrate these fields with less impact?
<config>
    <type>group</type>
    <internal_type>db</internal_type>
    <appearance>
        <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
        <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai,svg</elementBrowserAllowed>
    </appearance>
    <allowed>sys_file</allowed>
    <size>1</size>
    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <maxitems>1</maxitems>
    <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>

    <dce_load_schema>1</dce_load_schema>
    <dce_get_fal_objects>1</dce_get_fal_objects>
</config>


What about using a link instead?


<config>
        <type>link</type>
    <size>30</size>
    <allowedTypes type="array">
        <numIndex index="0">file</numIndex>
    </allowedTypes>
    <appearance>
        <allowedFileExtensions type="array">
            <numIndex index="0">jpg</numIndex>
            <numIndex index="1">png</numIndex>
            <numIndex index="2">gif</numIndex>
            <numIndex index="3">jpeg</numIndex>
            <numIndex index="4">bmp</numIndex>
            <numIndex index="5">svg</numIndex>
            </allowedFileExtensions>
        </appearance>
</config>



and in your template:


 <img src="{f:uri.typolink(parameter: section.fieldname)}" alt="{section.fieldname}"/>



